# A tricky OOP problem I never got my head around

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

Say I have two **.cpp** files: **oranges.cpp** and **basket.cpp**. They have the classes `orange` and `basket`, respectively. My `main` program generates many `baskets` which in turn generate many `oranges`. So basically, `main` will have many objects of `Baskets`; and `baskets` will have many objects of `Oranges`. If I have a function in `orange` that needs to know the color of my basket, how would I go about finding the color of the basket?

**orangle.cpp**

```
class oranges
{
    void whichColorBasket()
    {
        // get the color of the basket the orange is in...?
    }
}
```

**basket.cpp**

```
class basket
{
    int color;

    void basket()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)              
            oranges *o = new oranges;
    }
}
```

I know my syntax may not be perfect but how would I access the datamember of `basket` from a function in `orange` (`orange` is an object created by `basket`).

Sending the color a parameter isn't an option as there are too many `orange`s and the color of the `basket` may change during runtime.

I read somewhere that static functions would do the trick, but they only work if they are in the same **.cpp** file.

So, what do I do?

Comment: I see coupling here. This is your problem. You might want to pass a pointer to the color to your orange but that breaks encapsulation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Static functions are almost certainly **not** the answer here.

You would probably need to pass a reference to the "parent" `Basket` to the `Oranges` object, which it can then interrogate to find the colour.

For example:

```
class Basket
{
public:
    void Basket() {
        Oranges *o = new Oranges(*this);
    }

    color getColor() const { ... }
};


class Oranges
{
private:
    const Basket &myBasket;

public:
    Oranges(const Basket &b) : myBasket(b) {} // Store reference

    color getColor() const { return myBasket.getColor(); }  // Interrogate my basket

};
```

Whether you use a pointer or a reference will depend on whether the `Oranges` can ever move between `Basket`s.

Answer (score 3):

You need to somehow bind oranges to the basket they belong to - for example, by passing a pointer to the basket. How you do it will depend on whether oranges can change their binding to a backet during their lifetime and whether backet can be destroyed before all oranges in it are destroyed.

Assuming oranges never outlive the basket and never change the basket you do it this way:

```
class oranges{
public:
  oranges( backet* object ) { belongsTo = object; }
  void whichColorBasket() {
      here get belongsTo->color;
  }         
private:
  backet* belongsTo;
 };

 class basket{
     int color;
     void basket(){
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++)              
            oranges *o=new oranges( this ); //pass "current object"
     }
 };
```

Comment: how would I include these files. As of right now the first line of basket.cpp is `#include "oranges.h"` I'm guessing that referencing baskets in oranges will not work since it won't find baskets.

Comment: That's what forward declarations are for. At the top of oranges.h add the line: `class basket;` This will allow the orange header to contain pointers and references to `Basket` without including `basket.h`. (basket.h will have a `#include "orange.h"`, and if orange.h includes basket.h you would have a circular reference. The forward declaration breaks this cycle.)

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe my CS class never covered stuff like this.

Answer (score 3):

you'll need a reference in orange pointing to the basket the orange is in

```
class oranges{
    basket* b;
    int whichColorBasket() {
        return b->color;
    }
}


class basket{
     int color;

     void basket(){
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++){         
              oranges *o=new oranges;
              o->b = &this;
         }
     } 
}
```

I'm ignoring memory leaks here

Answer (score 2):

Your `oranges` object should have an instance variable `basket` representing the basket it's in. Add a method `putInBasket` which takes a basket and sets the variable to the basket it's in. Then the orange looks at the variable in the `whichColorBasket` method. If `basket` is `NULL` it's not in a basket.

This isn't the best design, though, cause it provides a potential for inconsistency. A basket might think it has an orange, but the orange's `basket` pointer could point to a different basket. Should an `orange` really know the color of the basket it's in? What's the use case? If you're only handling baskets, and you have an orange, perhaps the basket should have a `isOrangeHere` method, which tells you whether a given orange is there. You call it on all the baskets, and then you take the color of the one that returns true.

Answer (score 2):

Add a property to oranges that contains a reference to the parent basket. In the method for adding oranges to basket, also set the parent to the basket.

```
class oranges{
    basket* basket;

    void oranged(basket* bask)
    {
       basket = bask;
    }
    int whichColorBasket() {
       return basket->color;
    }
}

class basket{
     int color;

     void basket(){
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++)              
              oranges *o=new oranges(&this);
     }         
}
```

This syntax may be wrong but this is how its normally done.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that as a possible solution but it didn't seem very safe.

Comment: If the basket is null, it doesn't belong to a basket. What did you mean by safe?

Comment: I meant it sort of breaks encapsulation. Anyway how would I include these files. As of right now the first line of basket.cpp is #include "oranges.h" I'm guessing that referencing baskets in oranges will not work since it won't find baskets.

Comment: Why does it "sort of break encapsulation"? Your problem is very basic oo modeling ... you seem to are stuck tehre and need advice. IF you *also* need encapsulation then you have to understand modeling first ...

Comment: I agree, from the perspective of the current example, it probably is a bad OO model. But from the perspective of my actual code, I have to do something like this in order to use an API correctly. Imagine you had to subclass a bunch of classes and override their function. You can't really get around modelling your model any other way.

Comment: Actually, giving Orange a reference to its parent basket doesn't 'break encapsulation', it is precisely the correct way for Orange to access Basket safely. Your accepted answer (from @Covar), however, _does_ break encapsulation. Encapsulation means that you don't allow one object to monkey around with another object's internals other than through public interfaces. Passing a pointer or reference to Basket allows you to access its public interfaces. Passing a pointer to a Basket data member gives you direct non-public monkeying access.

Comment: This is also how Microsoft built their `Control` class in the .net framework.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you don't.  If you have to, there is
a problem in your design somewhere: what kind of orange would
know what basket it is in?  And what if the orange isn't in
a basket?

If you need to support this in some way, the "proper" solution
would be something along the lines of the Observer pattern; your
fruit would be an observer of its container; when you put the
fruit into a container, the container would register with the
fruit, and when you took the fruit out, the container would
deregister.  Clients could then ask the fruit for their current
container, and ask it whatever they want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C++ use a pointer in your oranges. `int *basket_color;` then just assign it the address of the baskets color `basket_color = &color`

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Most of the other solutions pass pointers to the basket object around. Passing a pointer to a single color integer instead seems safer.

Comment: Passing a pointer to one of Basket's data members is a pretty typical failure of encapsulation. Straight away, you have granted Orange the ability to change its basket's colour any time it wants to. Oli's answer (appears below for me) is the correct, OO-safe way of doing things.

Comment: My point of view was that passing an object pointer to another object would grant the other object a lot of privilege such as calling functions and using members. Passing a single member would isolate the access to only that variable. But I guess you're right from an OO perspective it would break encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

The way to avoid the coupling is to ask each basket if it contains a specific orange. If it does, check its color.

Why should the orange care about the basket's color? What about the apples in the other basket? Are they interested too?

Answer (score 0):

Your `oranges` class could have a `basket` member variable that references the basket that contains it. Then, when an `oranges` object wants to know the colour of its containing basket it just calls gets the value of `myBasket.color`.

The `oranges` constructor would have to initialise this member variable, so it would need a `basket` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Completely redid this solution as I had missed on a key constraint.

Another possible way would be to add a member variable to the `orange` class like so:

```
class oranges
{
    private:
    int m_nBasketID;

    public:
    oranges(int nID = 0)
    {
       m_nBasketID = nID;
    }

    void whichColorBasket() 
    {
        return gBasketList[m_nBasketID].color;
    }
}
```

And to set the value while creating the `oranges` in the `basket` class, like so:

```
class basket
{
   static unsigned int nBasketID;
 public:
 int color;
 void basket()
 {
     //First basket will have ID = 1 because
     //0 is reserved for unknown/uninitialized state.
     nBasketID++;

     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)              
          oranges *o=new oranges(nBasketID);

     gBasketList.push_back(*this);
 }
```

Additional modifications are as follows:

```
unsigned int basket::nBasketID = 0;
std::vector<basket> gBasketList;
```

I've made a couple of assumptions here:

1. There is a known value (such as zero) that can be used to represent an unknown/uninitialized colour state. This value can be used a default value in the constructor of `oranges`.
2. The `oranges` do not switch baskets *after* creation. If this use-case needs to be addressed then may you could delete the `orange` from the original `basket` and add a new one to the destination `basekt` or provide a member function to handle this case etc.

Comment: this is a very bad solution as the orange still has a colour when it is not inside of a basket and/or depending who is working witrh the orange he can remove it from one basket and putting it in another and forget to change the colour ...

Comment: I agree that the solution isnt complete since I missed "color of the basket may change during runtime" constraint. However, the concern that "orange still has a colour when it is not inside of a basket" isnt valid as colour is a member of orange & can be changed anytime. For moving oranges, see assumption #2 in the original post.

Comment: You are really suggesting (i) public access to internal data members and (ii) a *global* list of objects? Wow.